# How to execute other test cases in a TestNG test suite while waiting for one test case execution to finish

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using selenium webdriver with java and TestNG framework.
One of my testcases is to schedule backup and check if backup occurs on scheduled time.
after the backup is initiated at given time, it takes 12 min approx to finish backup.
I want to switch to other testcases meanwhile . Any ideas on how it can be accomplished using selenium webdriver

Comment: Add some more details... like the relevant testng.xml...

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can achieve this through `parellel` attribute in TestNG. The parallel attribute on the  tag can take one of following values:

```
<suite name="My suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
<suite name="My suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
<suite name="My suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
<suite name="My suite" parallel="instances" thread-count="5">
```

For more details see testNG doc.
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests

Comment: Could you please elaborate or point to some examples that I can use